# Each Image in FlowDocument is duplicating the original image

Tags: c#, .net, image, flowdocument

I have an object that has a collection of child objects which each have an image (ImageSource).

This collection displays fine in my WPF UI, each image is unique and correct.

I am trying to print a table of these images, however when I do every image is the same as the original one, although they may be sized to their different dimensions.

I have tried using InvalidateVisual after creating the Image object and after adding it to the table but no luck so far.

```
    public static void Print(MyObject obj)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog Printdlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
        if ((bool)Printdlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument {
                //Name = DocumentName,
               // MaxPageWidth = labelPrinter.MaxPageWidth,
                //MaxPageHeight = labelPrinter.MaxPageHeight
            };
            var table1 = new Table();
            doc.Blocks.Add(table1);
            table1.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
            table1.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
            table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());

            foreach(MyObjectChild item in obj.Items)
            {
                var row = new TableRow();
                System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image() {
                    Source = item.ImageSource,

                };                   
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new BlockUIContainer(image)));
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(item.Description))));
                table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(row);
            }

            IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;

            Printdlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "shipmentslip");
        }
    }
```